# Initialization of nested templated class members under enclosing class template argument

Tags: c++

How to get around with this?

```
enum SID {SID_A, SID_B};

template<SID sid>
class Emp
{
    public:
    template<typename T> struct s{T a;};

    Emp<sid>(){
        if constexpr(sid == SID_A){
            s<T>(){a = 0;} //error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
        }
        if constexpr(sid == SID_B){
            s<T>(){a = 1;} //error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
        }
    }
};
```

Compiler: clang 9.0

Edit -----

I would like to achieve a default initialization of struct member `s.a` depending on the argument of `sid`.
`T` would usually be an `int` or `float`.

E.g:

```
Emp<SID_A> emp_a; //here s.a = 0
Emp<SID_B> emp_b; //here s.a = 1
```

Comment: Your `s` type is `template`d on a type `T`, but that `T` is irrelevant for the constructor of your `Emp`. What type should `s::a` be for each of the `SID`s? It also seems like you'd like to define `s::s` (constructor of `s`) differently, depending on `sid` value from the `Emp` template. Is that correct?

Comment: So, what is `T`?

Comment: `s` is a type. `s.a` will never compile. You may either mark `a` as `static` and refer to it as `s::a`, or include an instance of `s` in your `Emp` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish `Emp` have a data member, `s`, which is a struct containing a numerical data member, `a`. This member should be an int with initial value 0 if this is an `Emp<SID_A>`, whereas for an `Emp<SID_B>`, it should be a float with value 1.0. I am guessing you want to have the freedom to associate additional values of type `SID` with different numeric types and values for `this->s.a`.

You can do this with template specialization. Declare the type of `s` as a struct `S` before the class `Emp`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

enum SID {SID_A, SID_B};

template <SID> struct S;
template <> struct S<SID_A> { typedef int   Number; Number a;};
template <> struct S<SID_B> { typedef float Number; Number a;};
// You can define further specializations here

template<SID sid>
class Emp
{
  public:
    S<sid> s;

    Emp()
    {
      switch(sid)
      {
        case SID_A : s.a = 0.1; break; // Note value is 0.1 to prove it's an int
        case SID_B : s.a = 1.1; break; // Note value is 1.1 to prove it's a float
        // define further cases here
        default: ;
      }
    }
};
```

Now:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Emp<SID_A> A;
  Emp<SID_B> B;
  std::cout << A.s.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << B.s.a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0
1.1
```